# C# syntax with generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics, syntax

I have a question about following variable declaration. What does that mean?

```
List<string>.Enumerator enumerator
```

List is a generic type, where string serves as a type parameter.
How to interpret the .Enumerator after that?

Comment: Note that in most cases you don't need to use this type directly; it is handled automatically during `foreach`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`List<T>` has a nested class in it, called `Enumerator`.

So the type definition of that is `List<T>.Enumerator` (and in your case `T` is a `string`).

**P.S.**

Actually, `List<T>.Enumerator` is a `struct`, not a `class`, anyway the type definition would be the same.

In fact for all nested types it's always `OuterType.NestedType`

Comment: Thank you. I knew that it was something obvious. Now I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this link, has all information about List.Enumerator:  [Enumerator at MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x854yt9s.aspx)

In essens the enumerator is used while looping over the list with for each:
"Initially, the enumerator is positioned before the first element in the collection. At this position, Current is undefined. Therefore, you must call MoveNext to advance the enumerator to the first element of the collection before reading the value of Current."